# Send .zip file as an Email Attachment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to send an email containing a .zip file. The .zip file is located at another url on another server. I am able to retrieve the file, attach it and send it. However when I get the attachment from the email. It will not open as it says cannot open *.zip.zip I have tried removing the .zip in the name but then the archive manager cannot open it either.

Any ideas?

Code is below.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('www.somedomaim.org')
  http.start() { |http|
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/path/to/file.zip")
    response = http.request(req)
    tempfile = Tempfile.new('files')
    File.open(tempfile.path, 'w') do |f|
      f.write response.body
    end
     attachments["files.zip"] = File.read(tempfile.path)
     mail to: someone@somewhere.com, subject: "Sending zip file"
  }
```

**[SOLVED]**

The solution is rather simple.

```
attachments['files.zip'] = open('http://somedomain.com/path/to/file.zip').read
```

attachments needs to receive the content of the file. .read returns the content of the file. My issue was that i was placing the entire zip file in the content of a new file. The above solution will place just the content of the zip into a new file.

Hope this helps someone someday. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you put attachments["files"] = File.read(tempfile.path)

Comment: I get a file as an attachment with no extension. When check the properties it is of size 0 bytes and type is text document. Some how I suspect I'm saving the http response to a file (which is nothing) not the zip archive.

Comment: http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html

Comment: I think that is more to make archives. I just want to move an existing one from a url to an email attachment.

Comment: solved. Edited question to reflect the answer. Thanks for the suggestions. Turns out i was opening the IO file not the content of the file.

Comment: It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: I would but wont let me within 8 hours. but for some reason I cant answer any questions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is rather simple.

```
attachments['files.zip'] = open('http://somedomain.com/path/to/file.zip').read
```

attachments needs to receive the content of the file. .read returns the content of the file. My issue was that i was placing the entire zip file in the content of a new file. The above solution will place just the content of the zip into a new file.